# Docker's NAT table output chain rule

Tags: docker, iptables, nat

i am trying to understand one of the rules in the iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat  --list -v
...

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 618 packets, 31267 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    any     anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

...
```

so this rule is trying to match destination address type "LOCAL" and not in the range of 127.0.0.0/8?

what address would it match then?
what's the purpose of the this rule?

thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This rule would match all packets originating at the local machine (since it's in the `OUTPUT` chain), destined to a locally hosted IP address which doesn't begin with `127.X.X.X`. Such packets are handed over to the `DOCKER` chain for further processing.

A locally hosted IP address which doesn't begin with `127.X.X.X` matches each of the IP addresses defined to the machine's interfaces. This includes dynamically defined IP addresses as well, such as those allocated via DHCP.

The machine's locally hosted IP addresses can be extracted by executing the command `ip route show table local type local`.

---

In order to inspect which IP addresses are actually matched by this rule, a logging rule may be added to the beginning of the `DOCKER` chain as follows:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I DOCKER -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix 'DOCKER CHAIN '
```

Matched packets will be logged in the file `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I don't think that is a commont... it should be the "iptables matches", i think?

Comment: no, but a comment looks like `/* addrtype --dst-type LOCAL */`

and that rule should come from something like:
`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j DOCKER ! -d  127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL`

Comment: slight typo in your last command; should be `-t nat` (lowercase), probably